# 12V AC 3A output from 230V AC

Tags: power, current, ac, transformer, 12v

In detailed Description i was about to run a speaker system which needs 12VAC 3A input power, i missed the adopter given by the company so i was searching alternative. For that i decided to make one myself so i can get 230v 50hz to 12v transformer from local shop. Now how can i get the exact 12vAC 3A output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: 3A VDC or VAC output this is unclear and needs to be defined

Comment: @VladimirCravero this is about transformers, not powersupplies

Comment: @laptop2d this is about understanding that if you set the voltage, the load picks the current

Comment: I need 3A 12VAC output

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should do is verify that you transformer is rated up to 3 A, otherwise bad things will happens. If it doesn't, then look for another transformer that can withstand that current at the secondary.

Note that you don't "get the 3 A output" unless your load requires it and your supply can source it. The 3 A rating is just a figure telling you what's the limit of the supply.

A 75 Ohm load will draw 160 mA at 12 V. If you transformer can deliver 3 A, then you'll be perfectly fine.

Comment: How can i ensure my transformer will deliver 3A, is there any criteria should i mention while purchase to my desired output

Comment: It should have a current, VA or W rating. Look for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think theorically transformer does the job itself. Your system will take how much ampere it needs. But to be safe you should look for a power supply from an electronic market or DIY project which you will use your transformer.

You can check various projects from here :

http://www.instructables.com/howto/power+supply/

Also as Enric mentions in his answer your transformer should be able to give 3A itself.

Comment: Oki as of now i need a transformer that can withstand upto 3A output so need to add any additional components as i mentions system will draw 3A